# Points on the same line

Tags: c++, geometry, maps, runtime-error

I was doing a practice question and it was something like this,We are given N pair of coordinates (x,y) and  we are given a central point too which is (x0,y0).We were asked to find maximum number of points lying on a line passing from (x0,y0).

**My approach**:- I tried to maintain a hash map having slope as the key and I thought to get the maximum second value to get maximum number of points on the same line.Something like this

```
      mp[(yi-y0)/(xi-x0))]++; //i from 0 to n

      And iterating map and doing something line this
      if(it->second >max) //it is the iterator
      max=it->second;
      and printing max at last;
```

**Problem With my approach**- Whenever I get (xi-x0) as 0 I get runtime error.I also tried atan(slope) so that i would get degrees instead of some not defined value but still its not working.

**What i expect**->How to remove this runtime error and is my approach correct for finding maximum points on a line passing from a point(x0,y0).

**P.S** -My native language is not english so please ignore if something goes wrong.I tried my best to make everything clear If i am not clear enough please tell me

Comment: Are yu familiar with `atan2`?

Comment: @Beta No sir,never heard of that.

Comment: @Beta Even http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/ is very cut-to-cut.

Comment: "Cut-to-cut"? If you mean the discontinuity at +/-π, yes, you must be careful about that, and also beware points very close to (x0,y0). Are these coordinates integers or floating-point numbers?

Comment: Are you dealing with exact integer coordinates or approximated floating-point coordinates?

Comment: Everything given is int more specifically (-10^4<= x,y<=10^4)

Comment: Do you know how to take the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers? Because the problem just got easy.

Comment: @yzt This was the first thing that came to my mind.I will be obliged if you can suggest some other way.

Comment: @Beta Yes euclidean algorithm and __gcd(a,b) this is what i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a very original approach here !

Nevertheless, a vertical line has a infinite slope and this is the problem here:  dividing by 0 is not allowed.

**Alternative built on your solution (slope):**

```
...
int mpvertical=0;   // a separate couner for verticals
if (xi-x0) 
   mp[(yi-y0)/(xi-x0))]++;
else if (yi-y0)    
   mpvertical++;  
// else the point (xi,yi) is the point (x0,y0):  it shall not be counted)
```

This is cumbersome, because you have everything in the map plus this extra counter.  But it will be exact. A workaround could be to count such points in `mp[std::numeric_limits<double>::max()]`, but this would be an approximation.

Remark: the case were xi==x0 AND yi==y0 corresponds to your origin point.  These points have to be discarded as they belong to every line line.

**Trigonomic alternative (angle):**

This uses the general [atan2 formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) used to converting cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates, to get the angle:

```
if (xi!=x0 && yi!=y0)  // the other case can be ignored 
    mp[ 2*atan((yi-y0)/((xi-x0)+sqrt(pow(xi-x0,2)+pow(yi-y0,2)))) ]++;
```

so your key for mp will be an angle between -pi and +pi.  No more extra case, but slightly more calculations.

You can hide these extra details and use the slighltly more optimized [build in function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/):

```
if (xi!=x0 && yi!=y0)  // the other case can be ignored 
    mp[ atan2(yi-y0, xi-x0) ]++;
```

Comment: Few things i would like to know.What do you mean by my approach is very original(sorry my english :p) and in your approach do we have to take maximum of (mpvertical,max) ? //max from my question

Comment: I meant original in the sense surprisingly elegant.  And yes, you have to consider mpvertical for a potential max as well.

Comment: @chotabheem In the mean time I've added another alternative using the angle. It avoids caring for an extra vertical.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming no other points have the same coordinates as your "origin".

If all your coordinates happen to be integers, you can keep a *rational* number (i.e. a pair of integers, i.e. a *numerator* and a *denominator*) as the slope, instead of a single real number.

The slope is `DeltaY / DeltaX`, so all you have to do is keep the pair of numbers separate. You just need to take care to divide the pair by their *greatest common divisor*, and handle the case where `DeltaX` is zero. For example:

```
pair<int, int> CalcSlope (int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    int dx = abs(x1 - x0), dy = abs(y1 - y0);
    int g = GCD(dx, dy);
    return {dy / g, dx / g};
}
```

Now just use the return value of `CalcSlope()` as your map key.

In case you need it, here's one way to calculate the GCD:

```
int GCD (int a, int b)
{
    if (0 == b) return a;
    else return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have already accepted an answer, but I would like to share my approach anyway. This method uses the fact that three points `a`, `b`, and `c` are covariant if and only if

```
(a.first-c.first)*(b.second-c.second) - (a.second-c.second)*(b.first-c.first) == 0
```

You can use this property to create a custom comparison object like this

```
struct comparePoints {
   comparePoints(int x0 = 0, int y0 = 0) : _x0(x0), _y0(y0) {}

   bool operator()(const point& a, const point& b) {
      return (a.first-_x0)*(b.second-_y0) - (b.first-_x0)*(a.second-_y0) < 0;
   }

private:
   int _x0, _y0;
};
```

which you can then use as a comparison object of a map according to

```
comparePoints comparator(x0, y0);
map<pair<int, int>, int, comparePoints> counter(comparator);
```

You can then add points to this map similar to what you did before:

```
if (!(x == x0 && y == y0))
    counter[{x,y}]++;
```

By using `comparitor` as a comparison object, two keys `a`, `b` in the map are considered equal if `!comparator(a, b) && !comparator(b,a)`, which is true if and only if `a`, `b` and `{x0,y0}` are collinear.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to divide the coordinates which avoids rounding errors and problems with dividing by zero, or calculate the atan which is a costly operation.

Answer (score 2):

Move everything so that the zero point is at the origin:

(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) -= (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)

Then for each point (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>), find the greatest common divisor of x<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>i</sub> and divide both numbers by it:

k = GCD(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)
(x<sub>i</sub>', y<sub>i</sub>`) = (y<sub>i</sub>/k, y<sub>i</sub>/k)

Now points that are on the same ray will map to *equal* points. If (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) is on the same ray as (x<sub>j</sub>, y<sub>j</sub>) then (x<sub>i</sub>', y<sub>i</sub>') = (x<sub>j</sub>', y<sub>j</sub>').

Now find the largest set of equal points (don't forget any (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) = (0, 0)) and you have your answer.

Comment: I think you might have meant `(Xi', Yi') = (Xi/k, Yi/k)`.

Comment: @yzt: No, but I shouldn't have capitalized X and Y in "...GCD of X and Y...", so I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

you can give this approach a try

```
struct vec2
{
   vec2(float a,float b):x(a),y(b){}
   float x,y;
};

bool isColinear(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 c)
{
   return fabs((a.y-b.y)*(a.x-c.x) - (a.y-c.y)*(a.x-b.x)) <= 0.000001 ;
}
```

Comment: How about adding an `abs`? `abs((a.y-b.y)*(a.x-c.x) - (a.y-c.y)*(a.x-b.x)) <= 0.000001 ;`

Comment: In `C++`, `abs` is enough. You don't need `fabs`. Let's thank to function overloading.

Comment: better to specify explicitly, I have had my problems compiling and wrong results between different compilers :)

Comment: You might have used a `C` compiler :)